# No sidebar Related or Linked links on most questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions

[image: Most questions have no Related or Linked links]

This partial screenshot is typical. Suddenly the Related and Linked sections are missing from the right sidebar on most, but not all questions. The label "Related" shows and sometimes the "Question feed" link. But usually that's all. Some questions do show links in these two sections but most don't.

Is there now some setting in my profile that I haven't found to restore these?

Comment: It's a bug. It was previously reported [on the global Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350569/the-list-of-related-questions-is-shown-empty)

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. It should have been resolved with the other report and appropriate fix :)